# Oracle: Creating an Index on a Table Containing Partitioned LOB Columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to create an index in a Oracle DD (**Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production**)
From the Oracle docs I read that to improve the performance of queries, I can create indexes on partitioned LOB columns. For example:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name 
   ON table_name (LOB_column_1, LOB_column_2, ...) LOCAL;
```

I've tried

```
CREATE INDEX fullsearch_description ON T_DESCRIPTION (UPPER(text));
```

but I got an error:

Erro

```
r starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE INDEX fullsearch_description ON T_DESCRIPTION (UPPER(text))
Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 55
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-02327: cannot create index on expression with datatype LOB
02327. 00000 -  "cannot create index on expression with datatype %s"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to create an index on a non-indexable
           expression.
*Action:   Change the column datatype or do not create the index on an
           expression whose datatype is one of  VARRAY, nested table, object,
           LOB, or  REF.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot build a B-tree on a LOB column. 
In your `case upper(lob) returns lob`. And oracle cannot use lob to build index.

You can use somthing like this. Because result of function index is varchar2. But i don't think this solution is useful.

```
CREATE INDEX fullsearch_description ON T_DESCRIPTION (UPPER(dbms_lob.substr(text,1,1000)));
```

On lob column you can use domain index.
 [Database Data Cartridge](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/appdev.112/e10765/title.htm)  - There are chapters about domain index. And how to implement it. `(Using Extensible Indexing, Building Domain Indexes, Defining Operators, Extensible Indexing Interface ,Extensible Optimizer Interface)`
Oracle provides several implementation of domain indexs. [Oracle Text](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/toc.htm).
* These indexing method are very complicated.